# android imageView scale

Tags: android, imageview, scale

I have an ImageView which is populated from database (the image comes from database). in the database i have images both portrait and landscape!! how can i adjust the imageView to scale it self according to the image width and height. I have tried many ways but no result! any help please!!!!

```
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <HorizontalScrollView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"

        >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/slideshow"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="0dp"
        >

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="300dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
            android:id="@+id/slide1"
            android:src="@drawable/ddd"
            />
```

Comment: Use `android:layout_width="wrap_content" android:layout_height="wrap_content"`

Comment: Why is there a LinearLayout inside a RelativeLayout?

Comment: Use wrap_content for relativelayout and imageview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code. `adjustViewBounds` attribute makes the `ImageView` the same size as image that you put in it.

```
<ImageView
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:adjustViewBounds="true" />
```

If you need specific `width` or `height` change the `wrap_content` value.

Comment: Tanx too much dear Max!